# How to disable the select field of a related entity in a form built using Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, entity, symfony-forms

I have two entities in my Symfony application; user and student with a one to one relationship.

I am working on a form to create student records which will also insert data into the user table.

I have created the [form](http://pastebin.com/J6dLty4K) successfully. The user entity has a role property (refers to a role entity) which as expected is rendered as a select field.

I want to disable this role select field so that only one option is selected when adding a new student. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the role field from within the controller and then setting the value of the role myself when the record is being saved. See below;

```
$student = new Student();
$form = $this->createForm('ReadathonBundle\Form\StudentType', $student);

$form->all();

$userForm = $form->get('user');
$userForm->remove('roleId');

// remove role field because we don't the user to be able to select this, we'll set this later
$form->remove('roleId');

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $student->getUser();

    // set role to student
    $studentRole = $em->getRepository('ReadathonBundle:Role')->find(Role::STUDENT);
    $user->setRole($studentRole);
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `"disabled" => true` to your settings array of the user form types specific role field.

To make it "more safe" you could filter the whole list of existing roles by adding a custom query builder method. If you select only the single row that fits to the current users actual role the select will only have one single option that could be selected. So even if someone would be able to modify the html code there will only be the fitting role.

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where('r.id = :role')
        ->setParameter(':role', $currentUsersRole);
},
```

Comment: I am adding the user fields in the student form using the line: ->add('user', UserType::class) What option do I need to pass into the options array to disable the role field? I don't want to disable role field from within the user type class itself.

Comment: To clarify: I want to customise the user fields from within the student form class.

Comment: If you would add the UserType by new UserType() you would be able to inject a parameter to the UserType's constructor. This might let you toggle the disabled option.